# How can my application find the Facebook Pages that a user administers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

I'm developing an application and want to let users connect their account to one of their Facebook Pages that they administer.

Is there a way through the Facebook API that I can discover the Facebook Pages that a user administers?

The method below seems to find all the FB Pages that person is a fan of (likes):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.getinfo#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with FQL:

```
select page_id from page_admin where uid=me()
```

(can try it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query))